# Python doesnot read full XML file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large XML file that iam updating with some data in excel.
When I try to print the xml file data, it only gives incomplete data as output.
I tried to use 'With' while opening the file as well but that didnt helped.
Can someone please help.
Below is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
from html import unescape
import xlrd
import lxml.etree as LE
import requests
import re


wb=xlrd.open_workbook(r'C:\Users\JPURSWAN\Desktop\xml\Legal-microsoftSharepoint.xls')
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

with open(r'C:\Users\JPURSWAN\Desktop\xml\legal-corp-services-qa.xml', encoding="utf8", mode='r+') as file:
    contents = file.read()
    #print (contents)
    for rownum in range(1,sheet.nrows):
        if not (sheet.cell(rownum, 2).value) == '':
            X=sheet.cell(rownum, 2).value
            Y=sheet.cell(rownum, 5).value

            soup = BeautifulSoup(unescape(contents), 'lxml')
            #print(soup)
            for a in soup.find_all("a", href=lambda href: href and "%s" %X in href):
                url = a.get("href")

                url=Y
                #print("Found and replaced the URL",X, url)
                #file.write(str(soup))
                print(soup.prettify())
                #print (soup)

file.close()
```

Comment: Without seeing the data, of course, we have no idea what you're doing.  Your code is only writing out the `<a>` tags that have your cell value.  And you aren't replacing anything in the XML file here.  Your `url = Y` just makes `url` point to a different object.  It doesn't change the XML.

Comment: And why are you retranslating the file contents every time through the loop?  The file contents don't change.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi Tim. Thanks for looking into this. Iam fairly new to python so making these mistakes. Yes I want to update the < a href of xml to values from my excel.
My XML contains so links that I want to replace based on a few keywords in those links.
Example of links in XML: www.example.com/xxx/keyword/yyy.
Excel has various columns and column C of excel has this Keyword and column E has the new URL that needs to be replaced.
So if any keyword from the excel matches the url in xml, it will be replaced with the excel url.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you wanted this, but it's very hard to tell from your incomplete specification.

```
contents = open(r'C:\Users\JPURSWAN\Desktop\xml\legal-corp-services-qa.xml', encoding="utf8", mode='r+').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(unescape(contents), 'lxml')

for rownum in range(1,sheet.nrows):
    if sheet.cell(rownum, 2).value) != '':
        X=str(sheet.cell(rownum, 2).value)
        Y=str(sheet.cell(rownum, 5).value)

        for a in soup.find_all("a", href=lambda href: href and X in href):
            a["href"] = a["href"].replace(X,Y)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: This is not working. Your code replaces only the keyword with the url in the excel. I want to replace the whole url.

Comment: I was able to modify your code a bit to replace the links. Unable to post the whole code here.
But my original problem remains the same, the output xml is incomplete. it leaves alot of lines from both the top and bottom.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible.  Are they XML comments?

Comment: not comments, but the tags.
I checked and saw that the read() file is itself not reading the whole xml file and is leaving most of the top part. The end part is correct though.

Comment: Is it because the size of xml is pretty big that it leaves the first half and only prints the latter?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by increasing the buffer of my system and pycharm both.